# How to resolve Python Pex binary file location

Tags: python, python-pex

Using the pex tool to package python proyects (https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.55/); is there a way to know where the original Pex file is located?.
Until now I just have been able to see where the "unzipped" files are located but need to programmatically resolve the original file location since the program can run under different environments.
I have a test script ~/print_location.py

```
import pathlib

print(pathlib.Path(__file__))
```

And the pex binary ~/print_location.pex

**Output:**/home/usr/.pex/installed_wheels/4d...e5/print_location-1-py3-none-any.whl/print_location.py

**Expected:**/home/usr/print_location.pex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Pex 2.1.53 (https://github.com/pantsbuild/pex/blob/main/CHANGES.rst#2153) at runtime a PEX exposes the original PEX file location in the "PEX" environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv[0] should be able to get you what you want.

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)